# clang-format does not honor ColumnLimit when aligning assignments

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang-format

We are currently investigating pre-commit hooks for code formatting. For c/cpp, we have chosen clang-format since it offers a long list of configuration options. However, we have other linting tools that only check (does not reformat) the code, one of which has a line width limit of 132 characters.

Now, this should not be a problem since clang-format has the `ColumnWidth` option. The problem is that I cannot seem to configure `.clang-format` to honor the `ColumnWidth` when also aligning assignments. Even when the penalty for excess characters is maximized (I even tried setting every other penalty to zero with the same results).

Consider the following `.clang-format`:

```
Language: Cpp
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: Consecutive
ColumnLimit: 132
IndentWidth: 4
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 10000000
Standard: Cpp11
TabWidth: 4
```

and the following obfuscated code:

```
int main(void)
{

    // code ...

    I32Tmp = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA((INT32) BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB()->CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC[index][typeindex],
                                 (INT32) BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB()->CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC[index][typeindex],
                                 (INT32) BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB()->DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD[index][typeindex],
                                 (INT32) BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB()->DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD[index][typeindex],
                                 VariableIn);
    I32Tmp = MIN(I32Tmp, (INT32) UINT8_MAX);
    OutVarThatWillCauseAlign = (UINT8) I32Tmp;

    return OutVarThatWillCauseAlign;
}
```

Executing clang-format (both official version 14 and master built from source) gives:

```
int main(void) {

    // code ...

    I32Tmp                   = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA((INT32)BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB()->CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC[index][typeindex],
                                                   (INT32)BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB()->CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC[index][typeindex],
                                                   (INT32)BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB()->DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD[index][typeindex],
                                                   (INT32)BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB()->DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD[index][typeindex], VariableIn);
    I32Tmp                   = MIN(I32Tmp, (INT32)UINT8_MAX);
    OutVarThatWillCauseAlign = (UINT8)I32Tmp;

    return OutVarThatWillCauseAlign;
}
                                                                                                                                   |
                                                                                                                                   | <- This is column 132
```

Is it possible to achieve what I'm asking for here? I have discovered that if I lower the `ColumnWidth` to 127, then `clang-format` respects the maximum width and chooses another format (which no longer extends over 132 characters).

Comment: just file bug report. How SO could help you with this?

Comment: Is it really a bug though? Since lowering the ColumnWidth makes it work, I rather like to believe that there is some penalty scheme that I'm missing.

Comment: If you file a bug report they can tell if that really is intented behaviour.

Comment: Understood, discussion is continued here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56444